# Boss automatically assume that the other side is right

Tags: japan

**For context:** My company and one of its partner(B) has a very bad communication line, the fault is mainly with B. I can't really disclose much, but basically, **to produce products for B, we need parts provided to us by B**. However, we don't have a clue when B would deliver the parts to us. It wouldn't be a problem if B deliver ahead of time, but they don't, more often than not the delivered parts came very close to the deadline, sometimes missing the deadline entirely, **with no notifications or communication whatsoever**. This makes planning ahead extremely difficult, **phone calls confirming which are coming, which are missing the deadline are made multiple times per day**, a very time-consuming process for both parties. As such, executives discussed and decided to incorporate this into our existing EDI line, and potentially automate this. On our side, my manager was given charge of this, but in reality the one doing the work is mostly me, as he has little to no tech knowledge.

**The problem:** The sample data came, with **a lot of errors**. I reported to my manager about the issue, but his response was not very helpful, to say the least. For example, the data given to us is very verbose, and contains a lot of additional information related to their inner-workings. The ratio of data we need versus unrelated data are also very high, around 1:20. When I discuss with the boss, he got this to say: *"Maybe I'm looking at it the wrong way. The data may not be junk, we might need those one day"*. Even data of where they keep those parts in their storage, the last time stock is inputted to their store, etc. Yeah, right.

To make matter worse, **these data and the data we actually need are labeled very badly**, so it's not clear which is actually the one that we need. There is this record that has a field saying "Exported quantity", its value equals the requested quantity. From that you would assume that this case had already been delivered to us, which then mean that putting it in "planned deliverables" list was a mistake, right? Apparently not. When asked, B's IT representative replied with: *"Yeah I can do that, but doing this means deviating from our goal, right?"*. **No other explanations, just that**. Well, from that, it's either B misunderstood my request, or the field itself does not actually mean what it is labeled currently, **both of which requires further actions**. Unfortunately this response further deepens my manager's perception that this is me not understand the data.

There are worse ones, but they are very specific to our company and thus would not be appropriate to discuss here, but generally from my manager's responses, it seems to me that he thinks that **I'm making a mountain out of a molehill**, his tone indicates that **he is reluctant to inconvenience B's IT department to work on this case**, that I should just zip it and make do with what we got. This is incomprehensible to me, as as much as we waste time making confirmation calls everyday, someone on B's side have to receive those calls, then spend a lot of time confirming on their side before calling back to us. This system working not only help us, but B's side as well. As such, it makes sense that B's IT department would at least have this in their priority list somewhere, even if this is not their top priority.

It is even more concerning that prior incidents with B's IT department regarding miscommunication did exists, one that is very severe at that. Just before this, it was discovered by me that the product data ordered by B (so data related to finance) that is sent to us automatically every day, was in fact **abandoned for years**, the new and current data is not sent to the official EDI line but privately to one of my company's executive, the person in question himself also didn't know that this is the case and did not check or CC the data to relevant department. According to him, B did not actively communicate that they have abandoned the old way of transferring data either. **If not for B ordering a new product and the order not showing up in the old files, nobody would have noticed this**.

**I fear that if this issue is not properly  resolved, a situation similar to the one above would occur once again.** Yet attempts to make my manager to take my concerns seriously simply don't work.

For the record, I'm planning to leave this company (work in process), and this could very likely be my last project here (my company don't have knowledge of this as of now). I'm trying my best to resolve this issue, to leave the company in high notes. What should I do to resolve the situation?

Comment: Businesses waste time all the time, especially to keep their clients happy.

Answer (score 7):

Don't play a game of telephone. You have identified the core issue: Communication is bad. So start to improve it.

First gather what information you need, make a spreadsheet of it. Include exact descriptions of the expected fields. Then schedule a meeting with everyone involved at your company and Company B. If your manager is reluctant do do this, tell him that he is right, you don't understand the sample data and you need clarification.

In the meeting go over the sample data and get an accurate explanation of every field. It is quite possible that you really aren't understanding the data. And that's not really your fault. You don't have the context and the descriptions you would need. Then present your spreadsheet and compare the values you get with the ones you need. Is there something missing?

Last, make them aware that changes to the data exchange format need to be communicated. Maybe incorporate a "version counter" into the data that makes you immediately aware if something changes. If communication between your companies is really that bad this will not help, and the format **WILL** break in the future. But now you can at least tell them "I told you so".

During the meeting, take notes. Afterwards, send your meeting minutes to everyone involved. Now you have a paper trail to "Cover your ass".

Answer (score 6):

Stop ranting and ask questions.

Is the information you need actually in the data you are being sent?  If not, that's a problem.

If it is, then ask or work out how to find just what you need. It doesn't matter that there's also lots of data you don't need. It doesn't matter if the labels are misleading. Once you know what you need, extract only that, and ignore the rest.

Comment: I still think that we should inform B to cut down on the "irrelevant info", since, although to our side it is irrelevant, but as I said, they are actually data related to B's inner-workings. Basically a data-breach on their side, if you ask me. That is not something that B should take lightly, even though our company and B have a very long relationship. Well either way the thing is still not usable, mainly because of the other details that I can't disclose. Still, yeah I guess I really did take things too far did I? Feels like my desire to get this thing done ASAP is getting to me.

Answer (score 2):

It's best to make a spreadsheet, or at least a list of all the data you need. And then request that the data is sent in that format.

I need sets of data periodically and had a similar issue. But once they had formatted and filtered the data to just what I needed and nothing else, it was fine. The main thing is I didn't wait for them to work it out, I gave them the format template I needed and don't accept anything else. If I receive anything else I just send it back.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. The problem is, I actually don't have the right to contact them, as I'm not the one in charge, my manager is. As such, I need his review before sending the request forward. This is a problem, as he is increasingly becoming more reluctant to contact the other side further. It would have been smart of me to do this from the very start.

Comment: Yeah, you should have done it at the start, but nothing to stop you doing it now. Up to the manager if they make it happen, it's not your problem to solve beyond that.